# PHP MYSQL error handling - prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I am trying to achieve secure queries using prepared statements:

```
if (!($stmt = $db->prepare($q['query1']))) {
    myException("Prepare failed: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error);
} else if (!$stmt->bind_param("si", $variable1, $variable2)) {
    myException("Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
} else if (!$stmt->execute() || !$stmt->store_result()) {
    myException("Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
} else {
 (...)
```

Is it the best way to do this? This code is unreadable. Can I use something like **try catch** block instead of **if/else if**? Will it work well?

Comment: Exceptions would make most of this redundant.

Answer (score 4):

As You suppose, this would be much clearer:

```php
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($q['query1']);

    $stmt->bind_param("si", $variable1, $variable2);
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $variable3, $variable4);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($result);
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        throw new Exception("error");
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

[code has been edited due to OP request]

Comment: I put bad variable in the query and it didn't throw any exception. Should I put execute() inside if() statement and throw new exception... or switch mysqli report mode? [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) . When I switched it to REPORT_ALL, catch statement started working. Without setting report mode ... nothing happens inside catch (I can make bad query, insert exit() inside catch block and it won't be executed)

Comment: Sure You should have `error_reporting` turned on... But instead of displaying of errors (most importantly on production environments) it is better to log the errors and/or exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($q['query']);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $s);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($result);

    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $stmt->close();
        return $result;
    }
    else
        throw new Exception("error");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    myExceptionHandler($e);
}
```

Will you accept that code? :)

Comment: this had to be an edit to Your question, not an answer, unless it is working well. I do not know what `$stmt` object is (is it a `PDO` object or a `MySQLi` object or some special DB object?). I do not understand what should the `$stmt->fetch()` be good for. I You have a statement, it need to be executed and there is nothing to be fetched after that... check my edited code in my answer...